Qt Android, how can I get MotionEvent.getToolType() equivalent?
I have a whiteboard that's a component extending from QQuickItem, as it's in use in some hardware devices I need to detect when the tool being used is an eraser, a stylus or the finger.
In Android in java that's as easy as using the method getToolType() from the MotionEvent received by onTouchEvent(), in Qt I am struggling with the events I receive from QQuickItem at:
void touchEvent(QTouchEvent *event) override;
bool event(QEvent *event) override;

But I am not seeing any way to get the tool type information equivalent to Android native java implementation.
Anyone could point me in the right direction ? Thanks in advance.
